# Website using old images... is this a cache issue?

Tags: ce-image, image, cache

I've built a site for a client that has a section which displays a number of entries.

For each entry there is a thumbnail.

There are currently 50 entries, and for just two of those entries the website is displaying the wrong thumbnails. All others are working correctly.

I'm using the brilliant CE Image plugin to display my images.

I've tried clearing my browser's cache, EE's cache AND deleting the contents of my 'images/made/images/remote' directory, but it's still displaying the wrong images.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: Have you checked the path that is being output in the HTML?

Comment: That's a good question. The images are coming from the images/made directory like this... /images/made/images/remote/http_domain.com/large/tp/12345/1234/image1/ImageName.jpg. I have tried deleting the contents of those folders with no luck.

Comment: OK so if you are removing those images are they being recreated when you visit the page? If that's the case it would seem the original image isn't being overwritten for some reason. Try uploading a different image with a different filename. It could be something between your site and the browser that is caching the image.

Comment: Do you have file expiration headers being assigned to the images via htaccess?

Comment: @foamcow thanks for your thoughts. Unfortunately we're pulling data from a third-party source so I'm not able to rename files

Comment: @JeanSt-Amand I'm not sure what that is. Could you explain please?

Comment: I think it would be odd for it to affect the blog and not other areas, but one thought that came to mind was whether expires were set on images.  It's a few lines in your htaccess file that, when present, effectively tag the images with some meta info that tells your browser not to reload the images and instead load them from cache because the file's htaccess-set expiry date hasn't arrived yet.  Do you see the "old" images if you visit the site from a computer that has never visited the site before?

Comment: Have you enabled the template debugger and checked the paths used by CE image? Also use the "net" tab of firebug to view the expiration headers.

Comment: My next step would be check the read/write permissions on your /images/remote directory.

Comment: while you're using CE Image, how are actually choosing what image is being used per channel entry?

Comment: @fccotech thanks for your suggestion, I'll try that

Comment: @foamcow I'll look into that too. Do you happen to know what they should be set to?

Comment: @StevenGrant I'm using the search feature within the channel entries tag. All images are assigned an index number, and the search chooses the image with the index of '0'. The strange thing is if I look at the images in the control panel, the image that is being used has an index of '7'. Even more weird is that it's just this entry that has a problem? Does that give you any clues?

Comment: Have you considered deleting the image from the entry and then re-uploading it with a different name? Since there is only 2 images that are causing problems this might be a simple and effective option.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem was being caused by the lack of a simply setting in the CE Image tags. As Aaron from CE Image very helpfully pointed out, by adding `remote_cache_time="360"` CE Image automatically checks each thumbnail image every 360 minutes (or 6 hours) and overwrites it if the image has changed.

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions!